# How to reduce git size (by deleting local old commits)?

Tags: git

I have a git repository which source size is only 1MB, but a 300MB .git folder. There's 10000+ commits in it.

I would like to keep my local repository small by keeping only several newer commits in local, how can I do that.

Comment: Does `git gc` help? Removing old commits completely contradicts the spirit of git. You usually want to have all history locally. Why do you have 10000 commits in such a small repo in the first place? Anyway, you can create a shallow clone using `git clone --depth N` which will only have the N latest commit in the clone.

Comment: I tried, not help much. But `git clone --depth N` helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Versions of Git prior to 1.9 are not particularly great at how they deal with shallow clones.  If you go that route make sure you are using a recent version of git.

Normally commits are very small, and even 10,000 commits shouldn't eat up very much space.  The blobs they point to may however.

Presuming you cannot permanently alter history

Try an aggressive repack to compress the objects.

```
git repack -a -d --depth=250 --window=250
```

Use a shared object store if that is viable for your situation by using `.git/objects/info/alternates`

If those don't work and history is fixed then try a shallow clone with `git clone --depth`.  Be sure to read the clone help page and understand what you are doing though.